# Submit form in <a href="form.submit();">

Tags: javascript, jsp

Sorry for asking a weird question...
I want to submit a form out of . But I want to allow users to open the link in a new tab (e.g Ctrl+Click).
Here is what I have already tried.

```
1 . <a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">Submit Form</a>
```

This opens the new link in the same tab and the old link in the new tab.

```
2. <a href="javascript: document.form1.submit();">Submit Form</a>
```

This does not let the link to be opened in a new tab.

How can I make it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use the [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) attribute on form

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will always open the link in a new tab, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

To open the submission into a new tab, use :

```
<form name="myform" id='myform' [...] target='_blank'>
[...]
</form>
```

[TO MAKE NEW TAB OPTIONAL]
If you want, you can add a checkbox, with this code attached :

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">Submit Form</a><br />
<input type='checkbox' id='newTabCheck' /> Open in new Tab
```

And in jQuery

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
   if($('#newTabCheck').is(':checked'))
    $('#form1').attr('target', '_blank');
    return true;
});
```

Or

```
$('#newTabCheck').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
   else
      $(this).removeAttr('target');
});
```

Comment: I did mention (Ctrl+Click) meaning this should be optional. Not always open the link in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `target="_blank"` in `<form></form>` Fields.

ie `<form action"your_url" method="post" target="_blank"></form>`

Comment: I do not want to always open the link in the new tab. I want to give user an option to do it. :)